# How do I cleanly write a method that takes any type of Enum to return out all of its enumerations?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, extension-methods

I have written two methods that take a generic enum and return all of its enumerations. The problem is that neither are best practise. So, I suspect that are could be another way that may take a different approach. Anyway, here are the two methods:

**One**

```
public static List<T> GetTypedEnumItems<T>( this T selected) where T : struct , IConvertible
{
    // must be an enumerated type
    var enumType = typeof(T);

    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<T>().ToList();

    return values;
}
```

This can be called using the following syntax:

```
var items = RolebackActionEnum .DeadOff.GetTypedEnumItems();
```

This cannot be best practise because I shouldn't need to specify an enum value that I just throw away in the extension method.

**Two**

```
public static List <T> GetTypedEnumItems<T>( this Type selected) where T : struct , IConvertible
        {
            // must be an enumerated type

            var values = Enum.GetValues(selected).Cast<T>().ToList();

            return values;
        }
```

This can be called using the following syntax:

```
var items = typeof (RolebackActionEnum ).GetTypedEnumItems< RolebackActionEnum>();
```

This cannot be best practise because I am specifying the Enum twice.

In short, best practise must involve specifying the Enum once as well as not specifying a dummy value for the parameter.

Please help!

Comment: Why not `List <T> GetTypedEnumItems<T>()`? It's not an extension method but I wouldn't _pollute_ every single `Type` with enum-related stuff.

Comment: Extension methods are a good fit only if you need to work on instances of a type. This isn't the case here, so don't use an extension method -- simple as that.

Comment: Good point - can't see the wood for the trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an extension method (which extends an instance because of the `this` keyword), why not use a simple static method ?

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValues<T>()
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
var items = EnumHelper.GetEnumValues<RolebackActionEnum>();
```

Comment: Idea of static method is okay, but implementation is no better that what OP have. IIRC `Enum.GetValues` caches the result for better performance, but you're losing all of them.

Comment: You're almost there. :-) `return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();`

Comment: public static class EnumHelper

Comment: Good catch :) What a shame :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks for talking about GetValues cache, I wasn't aware of this.